# Django SyntaxError

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Currently working on an exercise from PythonCrashCourse2ndEd. (Ch.18, Ex.8), and i'm getting a SyntaxError: Invalid syntax on urls.py. (line 13
path('pizza/', views.index, name='pizza), I have tried importing the file directly to shell, and it gave me the same error.

urls.py

```
"""Defines URL patterns for pizzas"""
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'pizzas'

urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index')

    #Page that shows all the pizzas.
    path('pizza/', pizzas.index, name='pizza')
    ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Pizza

def index(request):
    """The home page for pizzas."""
    return render(request, 'pizzas/index.html')

def pizzas(request):
    """Show all the pizzas"""
    pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()
    context = {'pizzas': pizzas}
    return render(request, 'pizzas/pizzas.html', context)
```

pizzas.html

```
<!--Inherits from base.html-->
{% extends "pizzas/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Pizzas</p>

  <ul>
    {% for pizza in pizzas %}
      <li>{{ pizza }}</li>
    {% empty %}
      <li>No pizzas have been added yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

Error

```
>>> import pizzas.urls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Heyale\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\pizzas\urls.py", line 13
    path('pizza/', views.index, name='pizza')
```

Comment: You are missing a comma after `path('', views.index, name='index')` ...

Comment: I'm speechless, I must have looked over a hundred times, and was unable to spot that. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Also missing `]` at end of `urlpatterns` list, but I'm guessing that was a cut-and-paste error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the comma after first path and also closing bracket "]" in urlpatterns. It should be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    #Page that shows all the pizzas.
    path('pizza/', views.index, name='pizza')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you also noted that it was just not the missing `,` alone for the `urlpatterns` list. But also you have been trying to use a view that doesn't for your pizza path `'pizza/'`.

What you have is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index')

    #Page that shows all the pizzas.
    path('pizza/', pizzas.index, name='pizza')
]
```

What it should be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'), # comma added here
    
    #Page that shows all the pizzas.
    path('pizza/', views.pazzas, name='pizza') # changed pizzas.index to views.pazzas
]
```

Answer (score 0):

urlpatterns is an array , so you have to seperate path elements with comma :

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('pizza/', views.index, name='pizza')
]
```

to get all the URL patterns in django shell enter :

```
import urls
def show_urls(urllist, depth=0):
    for entry in urllist:
        print("  " * depth, entry.regex.pattern)
        if hasattr(entry, 'url_patterns'):
            show_urls(entry.url_patterns, depth + 1)
show_urls(urls.urlpatterns)
```

Answer (score -1):

In urls.py you put the same path for index and pizza both. You are routing (def index) function for pizza.

You should do this, it will help you

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'pizzas'

urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index')

    #Page that shows all the pizzas.
    path('pizza/', views.pizza, name='pizza')
]
```